# How can I tell whether someone is the wrong height?

Tags: papers-please

A few times now I've gotten a citation because I didn't notice that the person was the wrong height. How can I tell whether someone is a different height than their information claims?

Comment: It's been awhile, but StarPilot's answer is the better one below.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Behind them you will notice some lines on the wall, next to the lines are numbers. Just make sure the numbers match.

[image: numbers on the background]

Comment: The people tend to bob up and down as well. That has often caught me out and made me waste a few seconds checking. Can anyone please confirm whether the discrepancy will be out by a long way all the time or not?

Answer (score 3):

You can highlight their height information and then their face in inspect mode. This will allow you to detain or reject anyone with fake ID or falsified information.

You can visually check it for yourself by looking at the height markings behind the people, but most people move around and bop up and down, so it can be difficult to tell visually if they are "close" to their reported height.